# How can swipe custom five sub views using uigesture recoginzier in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using *UISwipeGesture Recognizer but now working only two views we can do it as left and right but now Ineed five *UIview* to show as swipe please kindly help me?

I need only two direction as following :

@left direction.
@right direction.

I want to slide five view i.e left as well as right direction in my view.

Comment: @Naeem : i am trying to my custom view to show as slider. while user touch left direction then it will show first view and while user touch right direction then it will swipe second view. so i have total five sub views in my self.view

Comment: Instead of using swipe gesture, used icarousel with rotatory effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following ways in iOS.

1. Use `UIScrollView` add views which you want to swipe and then set `contentSize`, and set `enablePaging` = YES, and its done.
2. If your views are of in view controller you can use `UIPageViewController` and add set viewControllers property and set scroll direction (vertical or horizontal) and its done.
3. If you want to handle it via `SwipeGestureRecognizer`, you can still do that, add gesture recogniser in a view and then add all views you want to swipe through as subviews to that, and on swipe left and right you can bring next or previous view in front by chaining its frame, to track which should be current visible view and what are previous and next views, you can keep a integer proper and set its value to 0 at start,and on swipe left increment by one and on swipe right decrement, it should always be 0<=index<5.

   **Edit (Example code with Swipe Gesture)** Code is just for pointing you to right direction.
   I am creating views and adding them to subview in viewDidAppear, definitely you can do where ever you want (may be in viewDidLoad as well).

add two properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *views;// to hold subviews
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;// to keep track which view is currently visible
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL viewsCreated;
```

Now I am going to add some views and will add gesture recognizer to there superview

```
      - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        // Adding an if condition so we create views only once other wise you can take this code to viewDidLoad method
        if (!_viewCreated)
        {
             _viewsCreated = YES;
             int xPos  = 0;
            _views = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (int i = 0; i< 5; i ++)
            {
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    //  Create MapView object and add it to _views array
                    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
                    [_views addObject:mapView];
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    // Create tableView object and add it to _views array
                    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
                    //set tableView delegate and datasource
                    tableView.delegate = self;
                    tableView.dataSource = self;
                    [_views addObject:tableView];
                    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    // Create an imageView and add it to _views array
                    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                    //Set image
                    //imageView.image = <image>;
                    [_views addObject:imageView];
                    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    //Create whatever view you want and add it to array and subView as to self.view as well
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    //Create whatever view you want and add it to array and subView as to self.view as well
                }
            }

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSwipeLeft:)];
        leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSwipeRight:)];
        rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];
    }

}

- (void)onSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe
{
    if (_index<4)
    {
        UIView *currentView = [_views objectAtIndex:_index];
        CGRect frame = currentView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = -self.view.bounds.size.width;

        UIView *nextView = [_views objectAtIndex:_index+1];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            currentView.frame = frame;
            nextView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        }];
        _index++;
    }
}
    - (void)onSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe
    {
        if (_index>1)
        {
            UIView *currentView = [_views objectAtIndex:_index];
            CGRect frame = currentView.frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.width;

            UIView *nextView = [_views objectAtIndex:_index-1];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                currentView.frame = frame;
                nextView.frame = self.view.bounds;
            }];
            _index--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share code about SwipGestureRecognizer , pls create as poc and share.

Comment: @MukundRaj I added some example code, add these three methods and properties inside view controller and see how swipe left and and right is working

Comment: Thanks for sharing code now is working , but i will have to show data on particular view like as following: @ first view : Map @ SecondView : tableViewData @ThirdView : Images etc. so i am not able to understand above code could you please share code as simple format.

Comment: Above code is very simple and this is how you can solve your problem as well, your swipe left and swipe right method will remain same and you don't need to change them at all... 
Only place where you are creating your views object and adding them to array will change, I will update my answer with some more comments to help you out here

Comment: @MukundRaj I have update code, its not exactly what you want, but its a way how you can do that

Comment: Thanks you very much for help & i need same way just u have mentioned image,table, map etc. once again thanks:)